# Swift - Retrieving auto assigned ID from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase screenshot]

I'm making a simple app which displays the name of each item inside this database, and when the user swipes left, they can delete the item, along with its name and quantity. When this happens, I need to delete that entire node from the database. How would I obtain their IDs to do this?

For example, when user swipes left on `Apple`, I need to obtain the ID `KXsWXi1XE5cwdJiJQnj` and delete that whole section.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to associate the ID of a cell to the actual cell. You can do this by creating a list of IDs and appending to that list each ID from your database. So when the user selects the **second** item in the list, you can access the associated ID by going to the **second** item in the list of IDs.

For example:

```
 var listOfIDs = [String]() // goes in public scope of class

//Adding data from database to populate cells
for child in snapshot.children {
     // Add child info to your list of info being displayed
     // HERE YOU WOULD APPEND listOfIDs by this child's ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("ShoppingItems").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in


        if let snapDict = Snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict{

                let key = each.key
                print(key)

            }
        }
    })
```

To delete:-

- Delete from the local database i.e array and then call this function

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("ShoppingItems/\(key)").removeValue()
  ```

  Where key is your key for the value or cell.